# Horizontal ScrollBar in ScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, horizontal-scrolling

i have one strange problem.I add scroolpane to my one of two internal frames,iset both scroobars policy to 'ALLWAYS'.Vertical works normally but horizontal shows scroolbar but not the handle to scroll.Heres is what it looks like

[image: Problem]

I think its problem in JDK but i should be wrong.
I see some Threads here about this ,but no answer,maybe now someone can know.
Any ideas what it can be ?

Heres a code that is about the my scrollpane

```
JInternalFrame waypointsFrame = new JInternalFrame("Waypoints");
mapInternalFrame.getContentPane().add(waypointsFrame, BorderLayout.EAST);

topNode=new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Top node ");
InitializeTree(topNode);
model=new DefaultTreeModel(topNode);

JTree waypointTree = new JTree(model);
waypointTree.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);

waypointTreeRef=waypointTree;
waypointTree.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180, 400));
waypointTree.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(180, 500));



waypointsFrame.setVisible(true);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.setViewportView(waypointTree);
waypointsFrame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: Difficult to tell Without any code to look at. It looks like horizontal and vertical scrollbars are messed up. I would expect the vertical one not to display a handle. Could it be that in some place of your code, horizontal and vertical got confused?

Comment: I dont know what do you mean with "confused" but i cant see any code problem .I add here only a bit of my code,where is parent component(internal frame),and the definition of scrollpane,maybe you shoud see somethink there

Comment: What happens if you leave the scroll bar policy as default?

Comment: Don't set the preferred and maximum size of the tree. Let it handle these by itself.

Comment: I got it,it was in that prefered and maximum size.i set it to default and it works great.Thanks a lot

Comment: @MadProgrammer just a reminder: the _policy_ is unrelated to the scrolling _behaviour_ ..

Comment: More on preferred size [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @JBNizet  Good point.  See also [`JTree.setVisibleRowCount(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#setVisibleRowCount%28int%29) for the height.  I *generally* expand trees before adding them to the GUI, allowing the width to be better determined.